# Embedded images show as attachment

Tags: mandrill

I'm sending mail via mandrill smtp server.
The embedded images shows up as attachments.
When using another smtp host they are displayed inline as expected.

This is how the raw email sent via mandrill looks like,

```
--_av-wPsilWaNBD9LTkJ6pVYNCQ
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="header.jpg"
```

And that same email sent via my other smtp server,

```
------=_Part_2_149158871.1452888744955
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=header.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=header.jpg
Content-ID: <1.1452888744955@10.0.1.2>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or is this not possible with mandrill?
Mails are sent from a java application using javax.

Comment: Try setting the content-type to image/jpeg instead of application/octet-stream.

Comment: That was the solution, thanks!